# Git - Could not read from remote repository - Windows

Tags: git, ssh

i created a shared repository and configured SSH authentication and it works properly however when trying to clone it i'm having the below error

```
Cloning into "project"
Fatal: could not read from remote repository.
```

can somebody point me to the proper solution.

Comment: What is the url you have used for cloning the repo?

Comment: the repository is deployed on our local server. i have used the below command git clone ssh://servername/repositories/project.git the error message is not clear can i find more information about the error? maybe an error log file somewhere??

Answer (score 0):

I believe that either your server's private ssh key is different to your local private key or
you don't have the correct access rights.